# Showing projection is continuous if and only if kernel is closed

Tags: banach-spaces

I have a linear map $P$ on a Banach space, $X$, with $P^2 = P$ and I'm trying to show that $P$ is continuous if and only if $\ker(P)$ and $\ker(I-P)$ are closed. One direction is straight forward but I'm struggling with the other.

I noticed we can write $X = \ker(P) \bigoplus \ker(I-P)$ and now I'm trying to use the closed graph theorem to show $P$ is continuous.

So we take a sequence in the graph $(x_n, Px_n)$ with $x_n \to x$ and $Px_n \to y$ and I'd like to show $y \in im(P)$. We can write $x_n = a_n + b_n$ from the decomposition above and then $Px_n = b_n$ and since $ker(I-P)$ is closed then $y \in ker(I-P)$ and $x = \lim x_n = \lim a_n + y$ so $x = a + y$ with $a \in ker(P)$ (since it's closed).

I'm struggling to go any further with this and deduce that $y \in im(P)$

Thanks for any help

Comment: $\operatorname{im} P = \ker (I - P)$

Comment: Oh yes - should have realised that. So $Px_n$ being a sequence in $imP$ must have a limit in $imP$ and therefore the graph is closed?

Comment: To deduce that the graph is closed, you need to show that $y = Px$. However, there is a more direct way to show the equivalence.